# Intel 64 and IA-32 | Atomic operations including acquire / release semantic

Tags: assembly, locking, x86, intel, memory-fences

According to the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual the LOCK Signal Prefix "ensures that the processor has exclusive use of any shared memory while the signal is asserted". That can be a in the form of a bus or cache lock.

But - and that's the reason I'm asking this question - it isn't clear to me, if this Prefix also provides any memory-barrier.

I'm developing with NASM in a multi-processor environment and need to implement atomic operations with optional acquire and/or release semantics.

So, do I need to use the MFENCE, SFENCE and LFENCE instructions or would this be redundant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no need to use instructions `MFENCE, SFENCE and LFENCE` in relation with `LOCK` prefix.

`MFENCE, SFENCE and LFENCE` instruction guarantee visibility of memory in all CPU cores. On instance the `MOV` instruction can't be used with `LOCK` prefix, so to be sure that result of memory move is visible to all CPU cores we must be sure that CPU cache is flushed to RAM and that we reach with fence instructions.

**EDIT:** more about locked atomic operations from Intel manual:

> LOCKED ATOMIC OPERATIONS
>
> The 32-bit
> IA-32 processors support locked atomic
> operations on locations in system
> memory. These operations are typically
> used to manage shared data structures
> (such as semaphores, segment
> descriptors, system segments, or page
> tables) in which two or more
> processors may try simultaneously to
> modify the same field or flag. The
> processor uses three interdependent
> mechanisms for carrying out locked
> atomic operations:
>
> • Guaranteed atomic operations
>
> • Bus locking, using the LOCK# signal and the LOCK instruction prefix
>
> • Cache coherency protocols that insure that atomic operations can be carried out on cached data structures (cache lock); this mechanism is present in the Pentium 4, Intel Xeon, and P6 family processors
>
> These mechanisms are interdependent in
> the following ways. Certain basic
> memory transactions (such as reading
> or writing a byte in system memory)
> are always guaranteed to be handled
> atomically. That is, once started, the
> processor guarantees that the
> operation will be completed before
> another processor or bus agent is
> allowed access to the memory location.
> The processor also supports bus
> locking for performing selected memory
> operations (such as a
> read-modify-write operation in a
> shared area of memory) that typically
> need to be handled atomically, but are
> not automatically handled this way.
> Because frequently used memory
> locations are often cached in a
> processor’s L1 or L2 caches, atomic
> operations can often be carried out
> inside a processor’s caches without
> asserting the bus lock. Here the
> processor’s cache coherency protocols
> insure that other processors that are
> caching the same memory locations are
> managed properly while atomic
> operations are performed on cached
> memory locations.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to use (for example) an interlocked increment to signal I'm aquiring a resource. Thus means I need to use 'lfence' prior the increment. Why? Because I must be sure that every prior load operation has finished before I'm signaling.

Comment: No, there is no need to do that, it should be made atomaticly. Check my edit about locked atomic operations.

Comment: But an atomic operation has nothing to do with prioer or followed memory reads and writes?! Check this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kangsu/archive/2007/07/16/volatile-acquire-release-memory-fences-and-vc2005.aspx

Comment: Yes of course. The cache coherency mechanism only automatically prevents two or more processors that have cached the same area of memory from simultaneously modifying data in that area. **So you do not need lfence.** Check for more information in Intel reference chapter 8: MULTIPLE-PROCESSOR MANAGEMEN http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf

Comment: To be more clear: You do not need lfence prior the increment if you are using lock prefix!

Comment: Is this true for IA32 AND Intel64?

Answer (score 5):

**No.** From the IA32 manuals (Volume 3A, Chapter 8.2: *Memory Ordering*):

> Reads or writes cannot be reordered with I/O instructions, **locked
>   instructions**, or serializing instructions.

Therefore, a fence instruction is not needed with locked instructions.

Comment: That is what I thought. But for whatever reason, today I am unable
to code this highly simplistic mutex implementation, just as a test,
because no combination of lock prefix or / {l,s}fence seems to
prevent both threads getting the same -1 value.
Full source is at : [ intel_lock1.c ] : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1je5lNcv7nzS802BJweM4NVUcYYIwfxQn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I guess an mfence really is required, as well as the locked subl / xaddl .

Answer (score -2):

Problem still occurs when intel_lock1.c (available at URL above) is  compiled
on linux with GCC 5 or 7 without either of the args '-D_WITH_CLFLUSH_' or
'-D_WITH_HLE_' (so that neither CLFLUSH* nor HLE XACQUIRE are used) - 
the mutex_lock assembler now looks like:

```
# 74 "intel_lock1.c" 1
    LFENCE
    lock subl   $1, lck(%rip)
    rep nop
    SFENCE
```

So, I'm trying replacing {L,S}FENCE with MFENCE .

I still don't quite understand how two threads can end up with same -1 *lck value though.

Comment: Was this supposed to be an edit to your recent question?  It's definitely not an answer to anything, and certainly not to this question.

Comment: See updated [ intel_lock1.c ] : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1je5lNcv7nzS802BJweM4NVUcYYIwfxQn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is towards an answer, at least to me.

Comment: The updated version can be compiled with -D_NO_FENCE_ to not use any fences at all, or to use mfence with -D_MFENCE_ - still, problem occurs : both threads get -1 .  The specific question I was trying to ask is 
'why do two threads get the same value when both execute
   lock subl , $addr , 1
 and contents of *addr is 0 ?
' 
Is there any combination of Intel Atomic / Locking primitives that enables this decrement / increment to be done such that two threads must always
see each other's results and obtain different values?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my browser changed tabs on me and I posted these responses to the wrong question - I meant to update only:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657795/intel-64-and-ia32-atomic-operations-acquire-release-semantics-and-gcc-5