# What does 'Mutex lock' exactly do?

Tags: operating-system, locking, kernel, mutex

You can see an interesting table at this link. http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers

The table described,
**Mutex lock/unlock** `25 nanosec`
**fetch from main memory** `100 nanosec`

Nanosec?
I surprised because `mutex lock` is faster than `fetch data from memory`. If so, what `mutex lock` exactly do? And what does `Mutex lock` mean at the table?

Comment: I don't understand your surprise. mutex lock is preformed on data "change" (write) while fetch means "read". when no one acquires the mutex it does not do anything (happens when operations of "read" are done). do I miss anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked does not mentioned the architecture, but judging by mentions of L1 and L2 cache it's Intel. If this is so, then I think that by mutex they meant LOCK instruction. In this respect this post seems relevant: [Intel 64 and IA-32 | Atomic operations including acquire / release semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813297/intel-64-and-ia-32-atomic-operations-including-acquire-release-semantic)

Also [Intel software developer's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) can help if you know, what you are looking for. I'd read anything relevant I could find about the LOCK instruction.

Comment: hmm, it just means LOCK instruction? Then, it makes a sense(25 nanosec). Though, I wondered why did he use a term `Mutex lock`. `Mutex locking` is implemented by `LOCK` instruction?

Comment: I think that Mutex is a concise word of 'Mutual Exclusion'. So, LOCK instruction could be considered as Mutex.

Answer (score 18):

Let's say that ten people had to share a pen (maybe they work at a really cash-strapped company).  Since they have to write long documents with the pen, but most of the work in writing a document is just thinking of what to say, they agree that each person gets to use the pen to write one sentence of the document, and then has to make it available to the rest of the group.

Now we have a problem: what if two people are done thinking about the next sentence, and both want to use the pen at once?  We could just say that both people can grab the pen, but this is a fragile old pen, so if two people grab it then it breaks.  Instead, we draw a chalk line around the pen.  First you put your hand across the chalk line, *then* you grab the pen.  If one person's hand is inside the chalk line, then nobody else is allowed to put their hand inside the chalk line.  If two people try to put their hand across the chalk line at the same time, under these rules only one of them will get inside the chalk line first, so the other has to pull back their hand and keep it just outside the chalk line until the pen is available again.

Let's relate this back to mutexes.  A mutex is a way to protect a shared resource (the pen) for a short period of time called the *critical section* (the time to write one sentence of a document).  Whenever you want to use the resource, you agree to call `mutex_lock` first (put your hand inside the chalk line).  Whenever you're done with the resource, you agree to call `mutex_unlock` (take your hand out from the chalk line area).

Now to how mutexes are implemented.  A mutex is usually implemented with shared memory.  There is some shared opaque data object called a mutex, and the `mutex_lock` and `mutex_unlock` functions both take a pointer to one of these.  The `mutex_lock` function checks and modifies data inside the mutex using an atomic test-and-set or load-linked/store-conditional instruction sequence (on x86, `xhcg` is often used), and either "acquires the mutex" - sets the contents of the mutex object to indicate to other threads that the critical section is locked - or has to wait.  Eventually, the thread gets the mutex, does the work inside the critical section, and calls `mutex_unlock`.  This function sets the data inside the mutex to mark it as available, and possibly wakes up sleeping threads that have been trying to acquire the mutex (this depends on the mutex implementation - some implementations of `mutex_lock` just spin in a tight look on `xchg` until the mutex is available, so there is no need for `mutex_unlock` to notify anybody).

Why would locking a mutex be faster than going out to memory?  In short, caching.  The CPU has a cache that can be accessed very quickly, so the `xchg` operation doesn't need to go all the way out to memory as long as the processor can ensure that there is no other processor accessing that data.  But x86 has a notion of "owning" a cache line - if processor 0 owns a cache line, any other processor that wants to use data in that cache line has to go through processor 0.  This way, there is no need for the `xhcg` operation to look at any data beyond the cache, and cache access tends to be very fast, so acquiring an uncontested mutex is faster than a memory access.

There is one caveat to that last paragraph, though: the speed benefit only holds for an *uncontested* mutex lock.  If two threads try to lock the same mutex at the same time, the processors that are running those threads have to communicate and deal with ownership of the relevant cache line, which greatly slows down the mutex acquisition.  Also, one of the two threads will have to wait for the other thread to execute the code in the critical section and then release the mutex, further slowing down the mutex acquisition for one of the threads.

Comment: Really nice example given. (Y)

Comment: That's a very nice answer. In summary: cache access is faster than memory access, and Jeff Dean's mutex numbers (quoted in the question) are likely for the uncontested case.