# Thread behaviour

Tags: java, thread-safety

From a Thread perspective, what is a block, wait and lock? Rather,is it necessary to have all these three in any operation? For example, in a producer-consumer pattern how this things are implemented.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *blocking operation* is one that blocks the thread until the operation completes.  *Blocking* a thread is the process of telling the thread scheduler (usually the operating system, although there are user-level thread libraries) not to run a thread until that thread is woken up.  There are many kinds of blocking operations, and one example is file I/O.  As with any other blocking operation, the method doesn't return until the relevant operation (in this case, file I/O) has completed.

A *wait* is a particular kind of blocking operation used for thread synchronization.  Specifically, it says "please block the thread that called `wait` until some other thread wakes it up."  In Java, wait is a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).  The corresponding wake-up method is [notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29).

A *lock* is a higher-level abstraction that says "only allow a limited number of threads into this region of code."  Most commonly, that limited number is 1, in which case a mutex (which I explain in plenty of detail in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865673/960195)) is the preferred locking primitive in a lower-level language like C.  In Java, the most common locking primitive is called a *monitor*.  There is a notion of owning an object's monitor (every object has a monitor), and waiting on a monitor, and waking up a thread that is waiting on a monitor.  How do we accomplish this?  You guessed it - we use the `wait` method to wait on a monitor, and `notify` to wake up one of the threads that is waiting on the monitor.

Now an answer that will probably sound a bit like Greek, given that you are just starting with concurrency:  To implement the producer-consumer pattern, the most common strategy is to use two semaphores (plus a mutex to synchronize access to the buffer).  A semaphore is usually implemented with a mutex, but is a higher-order construct because it allows counting some resource.  So you keep one semaphore to count the number of items in the buffer, and one to count the number of empty spaces in the buffer.  The producer waits on the empty space semaphore and adds items to the buffer whenever space becomes available, and the consumer waits on the items semaphore and consumes an item whenever an item becomes available.

Now I've defined what these things are, but I haven't really talked about how to *use* them.  That, however, is worth several lectures in a college course, and is certainly too much for a StackOverflow answer.  I'd recommend the concurrency lessons in [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) as a way to get started with threading.  Also, look up college courses on the web.  Many schools post notes publicly online, so with a little searching you can often find high-quality material.

---

**EDIT**: A description of the difference between wait and blocking I/O

Before you begin reading this, make sure you're familiar with what a thread is, and what a process is.  I give an explanation in the first four paragraphs of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493421/different-between-task-system-threading-task-and-thread/9493446#9493446), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)#How_threads_differ_from_processes) has a more detailed explanation (albeit with less historical context).

Each thread has one very important piece of information: an instruction pointer (there are other important pieces of information associated with each thread, but they aren't important now).  The instruction pointer is a JVM-maintained pointer to the currently executing bytecode instruction.  Every time you execute an instruction (each instruction is an abstract representation of a very simple operation, such as "call method `foo` on object `x`), the instruction pointer is moved forward to some "next instruction."  To run your program, the JVM sets the instruction pointer to the beginning of `main` and keeps executing instructions and moving the instruction pointer forward until the program exits somehow.

A *blocking operation* stops the instruction pointer from moving forward until some event occurs to cause the instruction pointer to move forward again.  Certainly the thread that initiated the blocking operation can't make this event happen, because that thread's instruction pointer isn't moving forward i.e. that thread is doing nothing.

Now, there are a lot of different kinds of blocking operations.  One is blocking I/O.  If you call `System.out.println`, for example, the `println` method doesn't return until the text is written out to the console.  In this case, the instruction pointer stops somewhere inside `System.out.println`, and the *operating system* signals the thread to wake up whenever the console printing finishes.  So the thread doesn't have to start its own instruction pointer moving again, but the method still returns just after the text is written to the console.  So, at a very high level:

- Thread 0 calls `System.out.println("foo")`
- Thread 0's instruction pointer stops moving while the operating system writes "foo" to the console
- When the operating system is done writing to the console, it notifies the JVM, and the JVM automatically starts moving thread 0's instruction pointer moving again.  All of this happens without the programmer who writes `System.out.println` having to think about it.

Another **completely separate** kind of blocking operation is encapsulated in the `Object.wait` method.  Whenever a thread calls `Object.wait`, that thread's instruction pointer stops moving, but instead of the operating system starting the movement of the instruction pointer again, *another thread* does the job.  In this case, there is no external event that will cause the thread's instruction pointer to be restarted (as in the blocking I/O case), but there *is* an event internal to the program.  As I said, another thread will start the instruction pointer moving again by calling `Object.notify`.  So, at a very high level:

- Thread 0 calls `x.wait()` on some object
- Thread 0's instruction pointer stops moving
- Thread 1 calls `x.notify()` on the same object `x`
- Thread 0's instruction pointer starts moving again
- Thread 0 and thread 1 are now executing concurrently

Notice that a lot more work has to go into writing wait/notify code correctly - the JVM and the operating system don't do all the work for you this time.  They still actually do most of the work for you, but you actually have to think about calling `wait` and `notify`, and how they allow you to communicate between threads, implement locks, and more.

So there are two morals to this story.  The first is that blocking I/O and `wait` are completely different beasts.  In both cases, a thread is blocked, but in the blocking I/O case the thread is woken up automatically by the operating system, while in the `wait` case the thread has to rely on another thread calling `notify` in order to wake it up.  The second is that concurrent programming is harder to reason about than serial programming.  The toy examples I've put in this answer don't really do the second point justice.

Comment: According to you, wait(), notify() are to be used.So these operations block the input, right? so can we say that when we use wait(), implicitly, a blocking of IO happens...

Comment: @UNNI No, that's not the case.  A blocking operation is one that stops the thread from executing for some amount of time, and input is *one kind* of blocking operation, while wait is *another kind* of blocking operation.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: ,from your answer a wait operation is used \n for thread synchronization and also it blocks IO.So basically, when we use a wait() method in the program, these above mentioned scenarios are executed implicitly, right?

Comment: @UNNI `Wait` and IO are two **very different** kinds of *blocking operations*.  Saying that wait executes IO implicitly is like saying that a dog is implicitly a cat, since both are animals.  There is *no IO operation* whenever you call wait().

Comment: I would appreciate if you can explain the difference.

Comment: @UNNI I think you're getting hung up on an example that I added to illustrate what a blocking operation is, but I edited my answer to include a discussion with quite a bit more detail on the difference between `wait` and blocking I/O.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't necessarily need a lock or a wait just because you're using threads.  However, if you want the threads to exchange data, they are often useful.

Here's a good explanation with an example of the consumer producer model:

http://www.ase.md/~aursu/JavaThreadsSynchronization.html

Cheers!

Comment: this link shows use of producer consumer in 2 ways.One is using yield() method and other one is using normal wait and notify.But as a matter of fact, first method is not a standard solution where the above mentioned params are used.please see this link.http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/yield.shtml.And also, if there is lock() operation, still a yeild can be used.(Because, it will not change the ownership).

Answer (score 0):

**Block** : Prevent the Executing.
**Wait** : Suspends the current thread.
**Lock** :  When you lock it others can't Use it.

Consider online purchase when a customer buys a Movie Ticket
As soon as he chooses the seat. Others won't be able to get those seat at the same time(Locking those seats).

Comment: That Depends on your requirement if you know about the system you can decide whether to go with thread or not.
Better you expand your scenario to get better output.