# Storing a 32 byte object, on Ivy Bridge?

Tags: performance, x86, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture

I am trying to find out whether, on Ivy Bridge, its possible to write a 256-bit object which consists of various data types (int, double, float etc)?

I have had a look at the Intel Manual and ctrl+f for "32-byte" but the results were all discussing 256-bits of the same data type (so 4x doubles or 8x floats etc).

I am doing this as part of a lock-free design to ensure data consistency- load all 256 bits of data together, then extract each of the various components separately.

Comment: You can do large atomic operations on some versions of Haswell, if the chip has the TSX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions support.

Comment: @ZanLynx As the Wikipedia article notes, there is a bug in Haswell's implementation of TSX. Its recommended use is now limited to development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a Web search, and it appears that Intel does not guarantee that a 32 byte write is atomic.  I found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/307413) which suggests that not even regular **8** byte writes are guaranteed atomic.

Intel provides the compare and exchange 8 byte instruction which is atomic.

Bottom line is that I think you will need to take another approach.

EDIT: I forgot about the x86 lock prefix.  Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813297/intel-64-and-ia-32-atomic-operations-including-acquire-release-semantic), it says that byte memory operations are guaranteed atomic, while larger operations are not unless the LOCK prefix is used on the read/write instruction.

Comment: It should be noted that the linked page concerned *unaligned* accesses not being guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: Aligned 8-byte reads and writes (but not read-writes, except with lock) are also atomic, as of Pentium. Unaligned reads and writes of size 2, 4 or 8 that don't cross a cache line boundary are atomic as of P6. It's a moving target, perhaps not all online sources are using the newest specs (not that P6 is particularly new..).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I can align the data to a 32-byte boundary. Which two instructions would I require for loading and storing atomically (separately)?

Comment: @user997112 I don't think VMOVDQA guarantees atomicity (with respect to other threads, it guarantees atomicity with respect to interrupts). Since Haswell has 256-bit L1 Dcache accesses (2 reads and 1 write), it would *presumably* provide such atomicity (for aligned accesses at least), but Sandy Bridge (and so Ivy Bridge) only has 128-bit L1 Dcache accesses so the processor might not guarantee that a read or write is fully done before the cache line is invalidated (for a read with a write from another core) or changed to F-state (for a write with a read from another core). **NOT AN EXPERT**